# removing all numbers from all files in a folder

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a python script that will go a specific folder and remove all the numbers from the file name.

This is the code

```
def rename_file():
    print"List of Files:"
print(os.getcwd())
os.chdir("/home/n3m0/Desktop/Pictures")

for fn in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
   print("file w/ numbers -" +fn)
   print("File w/o numbers - "+fn.translate(None, "0123456789"))
os.rename(fn, fn.translate(None, "0123456789"))

os.chdir("/home/n3m0/Desktop/Pictures")
rename_files()
```

What I'm trying to do is remove all the numbers so that I'm able to read the file name

For example I want: 
`B45608aco4897n Pan44ca68ke90s1.jpg` to say `Bacon Pancakes.jpg`

When I run the script it changeS all of the names in the terminal but when I go to the folder only one file name has been changed and I have to run the script multiple times. I'm using python 2.7.

Comment: post your code here in correct format, not in a picture.

Comment: And when you do use an image, please inline it (click the image button, not the link button)

Comment: sorry about that im pretty new here

Comment: By "remove numbers" you mean "remove digit characters (0-9)", right?

Comment: yes i would like to remove the digits @qxz

Comment: is that the correct format @MooingRawr

Comment: your call to `os.rename` is outside your `for` loop - hence only the last file the `for` loop finds is renamed

Comment: thanks @asongtoruin thats exactly what is was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% on this as I am just on my phone at the moment, but try this:

```
from string import digits    

def rename_files():
    os.chdir("/whatever/directory/you/want/here")
    for fn in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
        os.rename(fn, fn.translate(None, digits))

rename_files()
```

Comment: thanks this worked also, but i had my os.rename() function outside my for loop

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is a little messed up, and that's part of what's causing you problems. You also don't necessarily need to change the working directory - we can simply just keep track of the folder we're looking at and use `os.path.join` to reconstruct the file path, like so:

```
import os
from string import digits

def renamefiles(folder_path):
    for input_file in os.listdir(folder_path):
        print 'Original file name: {}'.format(input_file)

        if any(str(x) in input_file for x in digits):
            new_name = input_file.translate(None, digits)
            print 'Renaming: {} to {}'.format(input_file, new_name)
            os.rename(os.path.join(folder_path, input_file), os.path.join(folder_path, new_name))


rename_files('/home/n3m0/Desktop/Pictures')
```

This produces a method that you can re-use - we loop through all the items in the folder, printing the original names as we go. We then check if there are any digits in the filename, and if they are we rename the file.

Note, however, that this method is not particularly safe - what if the file name consists entirely of numbers and an extension? What if there are two files named identically apart from numbers (e.g. `asongtoruin0.jpg` and `asongtoruin1.jpg`)? This method would only retain the last file it found, overwriting the first. Look into the functions available in `os` to try to work out how to solve this, particularly `os.path.isfile`.

EDIT: had some time to spare, here's a little fix to catch the error for renaming to an already-existing file name:

```
def renamefiles(folder_path):
    for input_file in os.listdir(folder_path):
        print 'Original file name: {}'.format(input_file)
        if any(str(x) in input_file for x in digits):
            new_name = input_file.translate(None, digits)

            # if removing numbers conflicts with an existing file, try adding a number to the end of the file name.
            i = 1
            while os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder_path, new_name)):
                split = os.path.splitext(new_name)
                new_name = '{0} ({1}){2}'.format(split[0], i, split[1])

            print 'Renaming: {} to {}'.format(input_file, new_name)
            os.rename(os.path.join(folder_path, input_file), os.path.join(folder_path, new_name))


rename_files('/home/n3m0/Desktop/Pictures')
```